# Sync local postgres db to a cloud postgres db, as a Windows Service

Tags: database, cloud-service, synchronization, postgresql

I'm looking for a software that will sync a local postgres db to a db in the cloud, like what Tableau can do with this [service](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_sync_local_data.htm).

This software has to be installed like a Windows service. It can be installed in any Windows machine.

The data will be pulled from the local db and refreshed to a postgres db, hosted in the cloud.

The way is always local to remote and the refreshing period is within a frame of a few minutes.

The service and the cloud host can be the same provider. Actually we are looking for a solution that will be part of the same ecosystem.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why Windows or `This software has to be installed like a Windows service. It can be installed in any Windows machine.`?

Comment: hi @TedTaylorofLife, legacy infrastructure... The company I'm currently working at, have Windows server where the postgres server-db is installed. But worse of all they have a lousy access engine that is doing ETL work that cannot be get rid of, at least not for now

Comment: but if you have a linux solution @TedTaylorofLife, I'm all ears

Comment: Is it always one way, local to remote? Should remote changes be synced to local, too? What frequency are you looking for? Once per day is OK, or any change should be synced within a few seconds?

Comment: hi @NicolasRaoul, always local to remote and within a few minutes, more or less. Let me put that in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several companies that offer the kind of easy ETL to setup for a loading to the cloud

- [Alooma](https://www.alooma.com/) for AWS Redshift.
- [StitchData](https://www.stitchdata.com/features/) for AWS Redshift and maybe PostgreSQL.
- [Fivetran](https://fivetran.com/) that can be a winner
- [Data Virtuality](https://datavirtuality.com/)